# How can I retrieve data from custom tables in Corda ?

Tags: corda

I want to retrieve data from Custom tables that I have created using Queryable State but the database port keeps on changing after every deployment .
Can I assign specific ports for every Node database same as web service and RPC ports ?

Answer (score 3):

## Setting the h2 database port

It depends on how you are creating your nodes;

### Manually created nodes

Edit the node.conf file that must exist for every node by setting the property `h2Port = x`, where `x` is your port number.

### Cordformation (in your build.gradle)

For each `node { }` block you can set the property `h2Port x`

### Driver

You can add any arbitrary configuration to a node you create via `startNode` by providing the parameter `configOverrides`. For example with Kotlin you can do;

```
startNode(<NodeName>, customOverrides = mapOf("h2Port" to x))
```

In Java you can do the same by specifying it as the 5th parameter.

### NodeBasedTest

In a `NodeBasedTest` you can provide the configOverrides parameter in the same manner as in the `Driver` but as the *4th* parameter of `startNode`.